# Switch - case in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, switch-statement

I dont know why i cant send data of "altMenuIndex" to "degisenMenu()".
When i change inside of switch manually, it works. But when i change like "int altMenuIndex = 2", it doesnt work.

The codes below show the "default" value.

```
class AltMenuDegistir {
  int altMenuIndex = 1;
  AltMenuDegistir({this.altMenuIndex});

  degisenMenu() {
    switch (altMenuIndex) {
      case 1:
        return Kutuphane();
        break;
      case 2:
        return KitapAra();
        break;
      case 3:
        return TalebeEkle();
        break;
      case 4:
        return TalebeAra();
        break;
      default:
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Bir şeyler ters gitti!"),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you passing it like this `var altMenuDegistir = AltMenuDegistir(altMenuIndex : 2);`?

Comment: Where should i write this code? Can you show me please?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are missing the pass `altMenuIndex` in constructor

```
  var x = AltMenuDegistir(altMenuIndex:2);
  x.degisenMenu();

  var y = AltMenuDegistir(altMenuIndex:3);
  y.degisenMenu();
```

So, why not change the degisenMenu method ?

```
degisenMenu(altMenuIndex) { // <====== altMenuIndex 
 switch (altMenuIndex) {
      case 1:
        return Kutuphane();
        break;
      case 2:
        return KitapAra();
        break;
      case 3:
        return TalebeEkle();
        break;
      case 4:
        return TalebeAra();
        break;
      default:
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Bir şeyler ters gitti!"),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
```

Then call this method through each button with passing appropriate index.

For instance, Kutuphane, call it like `degisenMenu(1)` etc.

Comment: There are four buttons to change view. Every buttons have index and when we press any of them, index changes. And view changes. 

```child: AltMenuDegistir().degisenMenu(),```

With this code, we see screen. So if i use four different variable, how can i write these variables to one "child"?

Comment: So you can change the method. Check the answer again

Comment: You don't need the break statements

Answer (score 1):

The default value should be set inside the constructor:

```
int altMenuIndex;
AltMenuDegistir({this.altMenuIndex = 1});
```

When you call the constructor yo can set the value:

```
AltMenuDegistir(altMenuIndex: 2)
```

Comment: Okay it works. But i want to change this index with four button. If i set its index, how can i change?

Comment: You should store the index in the state, and update it with setState... every time the button is pressed. And then you should put that variable to the widget like this:  `AltMenuDegistir(altMenuIndex: index).degisenMenu()`